# bash : vagrant commands not found

Tags: bash, vagrant

I am a beginner so please someone should show me kindness by showing me how to resolve my issue as a student. I've installed vagrant on git bash but every command seems to be telling me `bash : vagrant command not found` even vagrant halt is not working. please what do I do???

I wanted to install docker engine so i started by installing vagrant with git bash. Everything was successful so I tried

```
sudo yum install docker
```

The answer was: `no command found`

Then I tried `sudo -i` to get to the root and run the command again. Answer was `bash : vagrant command not found`

From here on all commands I try give me the same answer. I even tried to force vagrant halt but the same answer comes out.

Comment: Tags exist for a reason and that reason is not so you can trick people into viewing your irrelevant question. Add tags that are relevant to your question and none that aren't. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question. You should have taken the site tour when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an error that Vagrant is not found, try logging out and logging back in to your system (particularly necessary for Windows). $ vagrant Usage: vagrant [options]  [] -v, --version Print the version and exit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).